# Missing Access Token on IsAuthorized at Attribute

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I 
have been following the DotnetOPenAuth example of the oAuth authorization.

on the OAuth2AuthorizeAttribute i am always getting "Missing Access Token."
I have checked again and again i am passing the access token via the header and its been set nicely within the request object.

What could be the reason for that?

Here is the code

protected virtual bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext, out IPrincipal user)
        {
            var signingKey = ApplicationSettings.SigningKey(ApplicationSettings.KeyType.Public);
            var resourceKey = ApplicationSettings.ResoureKey(ApplicationSettings.KeyType.Private);

```
        using (var signing = signingKey)
        using (var resource = resourceKey)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

            // TODO FIXME dnoa doesn't support HttpRequestMessage - manually creating HttpRequestMessageProperty until they do
            var request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

            if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
            {
                request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] =
                    actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = null;
            }


            var requestUri = actionContext.Request.RequestUri;

            var resourceServer = new ResourceServer(new StandardAccessTokenAnalyzer(signing, resource));
            try
            {
                user = resourceServer.GetPrincipal(request, requestUri, _oauth2Scopes);
                return true;

            }
            catch (ProtocolFaultResponseException x)
            {
                user = null;
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In the Authorization header need to have the text Bearer before the access token for example

Bearer  gAAAALfeAiFpUFOY8bJggyQ